# Authentication That Doesn't Require Javascript?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API app, initialized thusly:

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication();
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication();
```

For calls to most controllers, it works great. However, it also requires a bit of javascript before client-side service calls are made:

```
function getSecurityHeaders() {
    var accessToken = sessionStorage["accessToken"] || localStorage["accessToken"];
    if (accessToken) {
        return { "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken };
    }
    return {};
}
```

The problem is that we have a certain type of controller (one that accesses files) where no javascript can be run during the call. For example, the call might be to:

```
  http://mysite/mycontroller/file/filename.jpg
```

...where the value is assigned as the src attribute of an img tag. The call works, but Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity is unauthenticated with a null name, so there's currently not a way to enforce security.

I'm new to Web API, so it may be a dumb question, but what's the way around this? What switches do I need to flip to not require javascript to add security headers? I was considering trying to find a way to force an authorization header in an IAuthorizationFilter or something, but I'm not even sure that would work.

Comment: Seems like you're combining 2 types of controllers in the same project (classic MVC and WebAPI ones).
What do you use to authenticate the page where your javascript runs in?

Comment: The pages themselves either require no authentication or use Angular JS, which I think just ends up checking for the authentication via JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out the solution to my problem.

First, I needed to configure the app to use an authentication type of external cookies thusly:

```
    //the line below is the one I needed to change
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
    app.UseGoogleAuthentication();
```

Second, it turned out there was a line of code in my WebApiConfig file that was disabling reading the external cookie:

```
    //this line needed to be removed
    //config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
```

After that, I could see the external cookie from Google, which passed along an email address I could identify the user with.